# Why are the posts of previous user being fetched(via get request) on first login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

i have a simple blog in which eash user has posts. on login user is redirected to home page which fetches all the posts of that user from APi. however strange thing is happening, after login user is redirected to home page but the firs get request fetches the posts of the previous user. this happens only on first fetch. If i refresh then posts of current user are fetched. can someone explain what is happening and provide the solution??

Following is the code of Home.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import { getPosts } from "../../actions/authActions";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => getPosts(), []);

  const { posts, userId } = useSelector(getUser);

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>
        Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper
        auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet
        justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo
        vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales
        ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis
        dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies.
        Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus.
        Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod
        lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a
        iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.
      </p>

      {posts.map((post, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>
              {post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..."}
              <Link href={`/users/${userId}/posts/${post._id}`} variant="body2">
                Read more
              </Link>
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  );
}

export const getUser = (state) => state.auth;
```

Following is the loginUser.js function:

```
export const loginUser = (userData, history) => {
  axios
    .post(`${url}login`, userData)
    .then((res) => {
      // Save to localStorage
      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      //Set user and is Authenticated
      localStorage.setItem("id", decoded.id);
      localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", true);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded.id));
      console.log(decoded.posts);
      dispatch(setPosts(decoded.posts));

      //redirect to home page
      history.push(`/users/${decoded.id}/home`);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      //handle validation errors
      if (e.response.status === 400)
        return dispatch(saveErrors(e.response.data));
      //handle other errors
      dispatch(saveErrors(e.response.status));
    });
};
```

setCurrentUser function

```
// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: user,
  };
};
```

authReducer.js

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, SET_POSTS } from "../actions/types";
import isEmpty from "is-empty";

const initialState = {
  userId: localStorage.id,
  posts: [],
  isAuthenticated: localStorage.isAuthenticated,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        userId: action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
      };
    case SET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

following is the getPosts.js function:

```
export const getPosts = () =>
  axios
    .get(`${url + userId}/home`)
    .then((res) => dispatch(setPosts(res.data)))
    .catch((e) => dispatch(saveErrors(e.response.status)));
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the action creator and reducer functions of `setCurrentUser`? I'm wondering if it's an async action, because then maybe `history.push` is being called before `dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded.id))` is resolved.

Comment: i solved it actually. previously there was actions page and i was getting the user id for get posts via store.getstate() . this user id was used for all the actions. now instead i passed the userid from the home page. this solved my problem. dn knw why this happened though. export const getPosts = (userId) => //passed user id
  axios
    .get(`${url + userId}/home`)
    .then((res) => dispatch(setPosts(res.data)))
    .catch((e) => dispatch(saveErrors(e.response.status)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing userid as arguement to get posts function. previously i was getting the user id via store.getstate() in actions page. now it was passed from home.jsx page.this solved my problem.

export const getPosts = (userId) => // userid was passed from homepage
axios
.get(`${url + userId}/home`)
.then((res) => dispatch(setPosts(res.data)))
.catch((e) => dispatch(saveErrors(e.response.status)));